# Are there reasons to consider complex valued random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

In all examples I know, we always work with real valued random variables. Why don't we ever consider complex valued random variables? Can anyone give an  example of such a thing?

It seems that if any complex valued random variable exists, it will be of continuous type; is this correct?

I also wanted to know, why discrete random variables are always considered to be finite?

Comment: All four paragraphs contain an assertion which is actually false (only paragraph 2 contains something else, namely, a question).

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity ! it's kinda confusing a stuff .. ! so may be i could not express it properly ..anyone interested may read the comments of me , beneath !

Comment: actually i wanted to ask in all discrete distributions and in other discussions we consider variables typically non-negative ..that's where i'm stuck ..can't we construct any r.v. that takes value from  minus infinity to plus infinity ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask exactly what you mean to ask.

Comment: somehow , i have got my answer ..so , for now i'm very happy ..will update later ..! :)

Comment: The difference between two Poisson distributions is a [Skellam distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution).  The probability mass function involves a modified Bessel function.

Comment: oops ! i'm a 1st year under grade student of statistics and probability ..!  :P well , i'll search it over google ..!

Comment: okay ..i checked your wiki link ..! and , thanks a lot ..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many discrete random variables count things: they are therefore generally non-negative real integers.  But while it is easy enough to construct discrete random variables which take negative or complex values, but less common that they measure something practical.

For example, consider the difference between two Poisson random variables (something you might test to see if rates of something have changed): this is is a discrete random vaiable unbounded on both sides.   In practice, if the sample size is big enough to be meaningful, a Gaussian approximation with a continuity correction will not be far off from the exact result.

Comment: excellent! seriously ! at least someone could understand my problem ..! may be it's because my quire was too ambiguous ..

Comment: but when unbounded on both sites how to construct a pgf ..? or anything slimier to pgf ..

Comment: See Wikipedia on the [Skellam distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) for the probability mass function

Comment: yes, i have seen..look , i have commented above ..!

Answer (score 2):

Discrete random variable are not always finite. For instance, a Poisson random variable is discrete, but in what sense is it finite?

It is not obvious at all that a complex valued random variable will have to be of continuous type.

One typically considered random variables with values in $\mathbb R$ since this is a very common situation. We like to measure things using real numbers since they have very convenient properties. In some sense, what a random variable does is translate the discussion from an arbitrary (abstract) probability space to the realm of real numbers (where then one can computer the mean, variance, and other quantities that require addition and/or multiplication).

It is certainly possible to define random variables taking values in different systems than $\mathbb R$. One can define random variables taking values in $\mathbb C$ or in vector spaces or other things, according to what is convenient. The idea is to translate the discussion from an abstract setting to a more concrete one where computations can be made. So, typically, one at least wants the ability to do some algebra and analysis: addition, multiplication, extracting roots etc. The most common such system is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: this is not something i wanted to know ! absolutely not ..!still i appreciate your effort ..! ..ANYWAY , MY QUESTION WAS CAN YOU GIVE ME ANY TYPICAL CASE WHERE WE CAN SEE R.V. TAKING VALUES IN C ? taking values in vector space is nothing to wonder ,. conventionally discussed vector spaces are dimensionally expanded form of R ..so , any more than one real valued r.v.s (i.e. a multivariate real valued r.v. will take values like that ) in fact i'm aware of complex addition of r.v. ..but what i want is an " example " ..!!! i guess now it's clear ! i will be impressed to have a typical one even..

Comment: statistics is not a subject where things are done without purpose ... in real whether something exists or not that really matters .on the face of uncertainty we try to discuss something that has a realistic consequence ..and in this way it is different from mathematics..! so , theoretically something can happen this little assurance is mere insufficient for a statistician .. at least it should be like this ..!now why theoretically something can't happen  to establish that logically (not just stating ' because we can't find any such example') is an interesting thing to do ..

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity ..
 
actually i wanted to ask in all discrete distributions and in other discussions we consider variables typically non-negative ..that's where i'm stuck ..can't we construct any r.v. that takes value from minus infinity to plus infinity ?

Comment: at least one place where complex valued random variables are used is in signal processing. Complex number are very convenient in the theory of signal processing and so complex valued random variables naturally arise in the analysis of stochastic signal processing. As for your third comment, of course you can have random variables that attain negative values. Any uniform rv on an interval containing negative numbers, or any Gaussian distribution attains negative numbers.

Comment: Gaussian is continuous ! is there any , discrete r.v. that takes negative  values /..i mean not a few selected values ,..but whose range is over -infinity to + infinity ?  actually the doubt did arise while handling pgf .. it is applicable for only r.v.s taking positive values  ..but , an entire separate branch , 'generating function ' for only positive r.v. ..i understand it's because otherwise we wont be able to introduce the power series ..!

Comment: but still confusion remains..when the r.v, takes only few negative values , we can change the origin and make that a positive r.v. and then make it pass through the procedure of power series ..but if it's range starts from -infinity then what measure will we take ? of course if there exists any such discrete  r.v. ...

Comment: look up Gaussian distribution!

Comment: oh ..i asked is there anything in discrete ...? Gaussian is not my interest ..normal is continuous ..!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of practical applications where one has to deal with complex random variables. The first that comes to my mind is signal processing. It is natural to represent the signal (for example in some communication system) by its magnitude and phase in real domain or with complex amplitude in complex domain. Complex amplitudes of real signals though can be represented with two quadrature real variables.

It is very hard to imagine modern physics not using complex analysis description of its systems. And in physics (and in real life) any variable can be assumed random in some sense (or case). :)